# FFMPEG Overlay image while also adding an watermark?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to attach a thumbnail to the first frame of the video while also adding an watermark, my command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i image.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,0,0)'" -pix_fmt yuv420p  -c:v libx264 -crf 33 -filter:v scale=640:-2 -vf "drawtext=enable='between(t,1,7)':text='@channel':x=10:y=h-th-10:fontsize=18:fontcolor=white" -c:a aac -b:a 48k output.mp4
```

But i get this error:

> Multiple -filter, -af or -vf options specified for stream 0, only the last option '-filter:v drawtext=enable='between(t,1,7)':text='@channel':x=10:y=h-th-10:fontsize=18:fontcolor=white' will be used.
> Filtergraph 'drawtext=enable='between(t,1,7)':text='@channel':x=10:y=h-th-10:fontsize=18:fontcolor=white' was specified through the -vf/-af/-filter option for output stream 0:0, which is fed from a complex filtergraph.
> -vf/-af/-filter and -filter_complex cannot be used together for the same stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is clearly described in the error -

```
Multiple -filter, -af or -vf options specified for stream 0
```

You are using -filter_complex, -filter:v and -vf

Try the command with the -filter:v and -vf  options combined either as only -vf or only -filter:v